# Material Ui React Radio Button Are Changing Previous Buttons Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a Material UI React Stepper Component. Into which I have placed a group of radio buttons. Unfortunately changing the radio button in one of the steps will alter a value selected in the previous and future steps. I have tried rendering the radio button and groups in a few different ways.

Please can someone shed some light on why this is happening. My code is as follows

````
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Stepper from "@mui/material/Stepper";
import Step from "@mui/material/Step";
import StepLabel from "@mui/material/StepLabel";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Radio from "@mui/material/Radio";
import RadioGroup from "@mui/material/RadioGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@mui/material/FormLabel";

const questions = [
    {
      "id": "43c98ce8-a07a-4dc2-80f6-c1b2a2485f06",
      "text": "My favorite color is?",
      "num": 1,
      "choices": [
        {
          "text": "Red",
          "score": 1,
          "color": 1
        },
        {
          "text": "Blue",
          "score": 2,
          "color": 2
        },
        {
          "text": "Green",
          "score": 3,
          "color": 3
        },
        {
          "text": "Yellow",
          "score": 4,
          "color": 4
        },
        {
          "text": "Orange",
          "score": 5,
          "color": 5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "d50a597f-632b-4f7b-89e6-6d85b50fd1c9",
      "text": "My favorite food is?",
      "num": 2,
      "choices": [
        {
          "text": "Pasta",
          "score": 5,
          "color": 1
        },
        {
          "text": "Pizza",
          "score": 4,
          "color": 2
        },
        {
          "text": "Burger",
          "score": 3,
          "color": 3
        },
      ]
    },
    {
        "id": "f6076eea-56ae-4b46-97f1-5f94a7676c96",
        "text": "My favorite mode of transport is?",
        "num": 3,
        "choices": [
          {
            "text": "Train",
            "score": 1,
            "color": 1
          },
          {
            "text": "Plane",
            "score": 2,
            "color": 2
          },
          {
            "text": "Car",
            "score": 3,
            "color": 3
          },
          {
            "text": "Boat",
            "score": 4,
            "color": 4
          },
        ]
    }
];

    const choices = [];
    
function Questions() {
    const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
    const [skipped, setSkipped] = useState(new Set());
    
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target);
      };
  
    const isStepOptional = (step) => {
      return step === 1;
    };
  
    const isStepSkipped = (step) => {
      return skipped.has(step);
    };
  
    const handleNext = () => {
      let newSkipped = skipped;
      if (isStepSkipped(activeStep)) {
        newSkipped = new Set(newSkipped.values());
        newSkipped.delete(activeStep);
      }
  
      setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
      setSkipped(newSkipped);
    };
  
    const handleBack = () => {
      setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
    };
  
    const handleSkip = () => {
      if (!isStepOptional(activeStep)) {
        // You probably want to guard against something like this,
        // it should never occur unless someone's actively trying to break something.
        throw new Error("You can't skip a step that isn't optional.");
      }
  
      setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
      setSkipped((prevSkipped) => {
        const newSkipped = new Set(prevSkipped.values());
        newSkipped.add(activeStep);
        return newSkipped;
      });
    };
  
    const handleReset = () => {
      setActiveStep(0);
    };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%", borderRadius: "5px",
    height: "315px",
    padding: "25px",
    overflow: "hidden",
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    width: "70%",
    zIndex: "10",
    top: "0",
    left: "0",
    right: "0",
    bottom: "0",
    margin: "auto" }}>
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep}>
        {questions.map((question, index) => {
          const stepProps = {};
          const labelProps = {};
          if (isStepSkipped(index)) {
            stepProps.completed = false;
          }
          return (
            <Step key={question.text} {...stepProps}>
              <StepLabel {...labelProps}>{question.text}</StepLabel>
            </Step>
          );
        })}
      </Stepper>

      <FormControl sx={{ margin: "0 auto" }}>
        {/* <FormLabel id="demo-radio-buttons-group-label">Gender</FormLabel> */}
        <RadioGroup
          aria-labelledby="demo-radio-buttons-group-label"
          name="radio-buttons-group"
        >
        {questions[activeStep].choices.map((question, index) => 
        {
            return (
                <FormControlLabel
                id={index}
            control={
              <Radio
                inputProps={{
                  "aria-label": question.text
                }}
              />
            }
            value={question.score}
            label={question.text}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
            )
        })}
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
      {activeStep === questions.length ? (
        <Fragment>
          <Typography >
            All steps completed - you&apos;re finished
          </Typography>
          <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", pt: 2, backgroudColor: "white" }}>
            <Box sx={{ flex: "1 1 auto" }} />
            <Button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</Button>
          </Box>
        </Fragment>
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <Typography sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 1 }}>Step {activeStep + 1}</Typography>
          <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", pt: 2, backgroudColor: "white" }}>
            <Button
              color="inherit"
              disabled={activeStep === 0}
              onClick={handleBack}
              sx={{ mr: 1 }}
            >
              Back
            </Button>
            <Box sx={{ flex: "1 1 auto", backgroudColor: "white" }} />
            {isStepOptional(activeStep) && (
              <Button color="inherit" onClick={handleSkip} sx={{ mr: 1 }}>
                Skip
              </Button>
            )}

            <Button onClick={handleNext}>
              {activeStep === questions.length - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next"}
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Box>
  )
}

export default Questions;```
`
for example selecting pizza in the below image will change the answer of my favorite color
[![example][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub8ao.png`
````

Comment: could you post minimal example for your issue?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub8ao.png

for example selecting pizza in the above image will change the answer of my favorite color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you were not saving tha answers you got on the steps. Your handleChange function was doing nothing so i just edited a little bit of code and created a new prop to save depending on the question index.

```
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Stepper from "@mui/material/Stepper";
import Step from "@mui/material/Step";
import StepLabel from "@mui/material/StepLabel";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Radio from "@mui/material/Radio";
import RadioGroup from "@mui/material/RadioGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@mui/material/FormLabel";
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
const questions = [
  {
    id: "43c98ce8-a07a-4dc2-80f6-c1b2a2485f06",
    text: "My favorite color is?",
    num: 1,
    choices: [
      {
        text: "Red",
        score: 1,
        color: 1
      },
      {
        text: "Blue",
        score: 2,
        color: 2
      },
      {
        text: "Green",
        score: 3,
        color: 3
      },
      {
        text: "Yellow",
        score: 4,
        color: 4
      },
      {
        text: "Orange",
        score: 5,
        color: 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "d50a597f-632b-4f7b-89e6-6d85b50fd1c9",
    text: "My favorite food is?",
    num: 2,
    choices: [
      {
        text: "Pasta",
        score: 5,
        color: 1
      },
      {
        text: "Pizza",
        score: 4,
        color: 2
      },
      {
        text: "Burger",
        score: 3,
        color: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "f6076eea-56ae-4b46-97f1-5f94a7676c96",
    text: "My favorite mode of transport is?",
    num: 3,
    choices: [
      {
        text: "Train",
        score: 1,
        color: 1
      },
      {
        text: "Plane",
        score: 2,
        color: 2
      },
      {
        text: "Car",
        score: 3,
        color: 3
      },
      {
        text: "Boat",
        score: 4,
        color: 4
      }
    ]
  }
];


export default function Questions() {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const [skipped, setSkipped] = useState(new Set());
  const [selectedChoices,setSelectedChoices] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (event) => {
      setSelectedChoices({
        ...selectedChoices,
        [activeStep]: event.target.value});
  };

  const isStepOptional = (step) => {
    return step === 1;
  };

  const isStepSkipped = (step) => {
    return skipped.has(step);
  };

  const handleNext = () => {
    let newSkipped = skipped;
    if (isStepSkipped(activeStep)) {
      newSkipped = new Set(newSkipped.values());
      newSkipped.delete(activeStep);
    }

    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
    setSkipped(newSkipped);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const handleSkip = () => {
    if (!isStepOptional(activeStep)) {
      // You probably want to guard against something like this,
      // it should never occur unless someone's actively trying to break something.
      throw new Error("You can't skip a step that isn't optional.");
    }

    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
    setSkipped((prevSkipped) => {
      const newSkipped = new Set(prevSkipped.values());
      newSkipped.add(activeStep);
      return newSkipped;
    });
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        width: "100%",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        height: "315px",
        padding: "25px",
        overflow: "hidden",
        position: "absolute",
        backgroundColor: "white",
        width: "70%",
        zIndex: "10",
        top: "0",
        left: "0",
        right: "0",
        bottom: "0",
        margin: "auto"
      }}
    >
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep}>
        {questions.map((question, index) => {
          const stepProps = {};
          const labelProps = {};
          if (isStepSkipped(index)) {
            stepProps.completed = false;
          }
          return (
            <Step key={question.text} {...stepProps}>
              <StepLabel {...labelProps}>{question.text}</StepLabel>
            </Step>
          );
        })}
      </Stepper>

      <FormControl sx={{ margin: "0 auto" }}>
        
        {/* <FormLabel id="demo-radio-buttons-group-label">Gender</FormLabel> */}
        <RadioGroup
          aria-labelledby="demo-radio-buttons-group-label"
          name="radio-buttons-group"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value = {`${selectedChoices[activeStep]}`}
        >
          {questions[activeStep].choices.map((question, index) => {
            return (
              <FormControlLabel
                control={
                  <Radio
                    inputProps={{
                      "aria-label": question.text
                    }}
                  />
                }
                value={index}
                label={question.text}
                key = {index}
              />
            );
          })}
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
      {activeStep === questions.length ? (
        <Fragment>
          <Typography>All steps completed - you&apos;re finished</Typography>
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
              pt: 2,
              backgroudColor: "white"
            }}
          >
            <Box sx={{ flex: "1 1 auto" }} />
            <Button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</Button>
          </Box>
        </Fragment>
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <Typography sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 1 }}>Step {activeStep + 1}</Typography>
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
              pt: 2,
              backgroudColor: "white"
            }}
          >
            <Button
              color="inherit"
              disabled={activeStep === 0}
              onClick={handleBack}
              sx={{ mr: 1 }}
            >
              Back
            </Button>
            <Box sx={{ flex: "1 1 auto", backgroudColor: "white" }} />
            {isStepOptional(activeStep) && (
              <Button color="inherit" onClick={handleSkip} sx={{ mr: 1 }}>
                Skip
              </Button>
            )}

            <Button onClick={handleNext}>
              {activeStep === questions.length - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next"}
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Now when you click a radio button it will save it on the object using the index as key. Also if you want you can set special keys to each question. After that i am just passing the saved values to **RadioGroup** element to make radio button selected on render.

Also i created a sandbox: [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-rain-imhtju?file=/demo.jsx)